# fclose() causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen, fclose

I have a tab-delimited text file that I am parsing. Its first column contains strings of the format `chrX`, where `X` denotes a set of strings, e.g., "1", "2", ..., "X", "Y".

These are each stored in a `char*` called `chromosome`, as the file is parsed.

The text file is sorted on the first column lexicographically, i.e., I will have a number of rows starting with "chr1", and then "chr2", etc.

At each "chrX" entry, I need to open another file that is associated with this entry:

```
FILE *merbaseIn;

// loop through rows...

if (chromosome == NULL)                                                                                                                                                   
    openSourceFile(&chromosome, fieldArray[i], &merbaseIn, GENPATHIN);                                                                                                      
else {                                                                                                                                                                    
    if (strcmp(chromosome, fieldArray[i]) != 0) { // new chromosome                                                                                                   
        fclose(merbaseIn); // close old chromosome FILE ptr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        free(chromosome); // free old chromosome ptr                                                                                                                          
        openSourceFile(&chromosome, fieldArray[i], &merbaseIn, GENPATHIN); // set up new chromosome FILE ptr                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                       
}  
// parse row
```

I have the function `openSourceFile` that is defined as follows:

```
void openSourceFile (char** chrome, const char* field, FILE** filePtr, const char *path) {
    char filename[100];                                                                                                                                                           
    *chrome = (char *) malloc ((size_t) strlen(field));
    if (*chrome == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                        
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for chromosome name!");                                                                                                      
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                             

    strcpy(*chrome, field);                                                                                                                                                       
    sprintf(filename,"%s%s.fa", path, field);                                                                                                                                     

    *filePtr = fopen(filename, "r");                                                                                                                                              
    if (*filePtr == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                       
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not open fasta source file %s\n", filename);                                                                                                  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

The problem is that my application quits with a Segmentation Fault going from the first chromosome to the second (from `chr1` to `chr2`) at the following line, where I close the first chromosome file that I opened:

```
fclose(merbaseIn);
```

I know I'm not passing `fclose` a NULL pointer, because up until the Segmentation Fault, I am reading data from this file. I can even wrap this in a conditional and I still get the Fault:

```
if (merbaseIn != NULL) {
    fclose(merbaseIn);
}
```

Further, I know `openSourceFile` works (at least for `chr1`, when setting up the first file handle of `FILE*`) because my application parses `chr1` rows and reads data from the `FILE*` source file correctly.

What is it about this `fclose` call that is causing a Segmentation Fault to occur?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
valgrind --db-attach=yes --leak-check=yes --tool=memcheck --num-callers=16 --leak-resolution=high ./yourprogram args
```

It's very likely the segfault is caused by memory corruption on the heap, not anything that's affecting locals.  [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html) will immediately show you the first wrong access you make.

Edit: The `--db-attach` option to `valgrind` has been deprecated since release 3.10.0 in 2014. The release notes state:

```
The built-in GDB server capabilities are superior and should be used
instead. Learn more here:
```

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver

Comment: I was not running `free` on the pointers within the double pointer. I was also not freeing pointers elsewhere. I scrapped this app and wrote it from scratch, running `valgrind` as I went along to make sure I was managing memory properly. Thanks for pointing me to this tool!

Comment: Yeah, valgrind taught me: 1) how everyone was right and I should have only used smart (auto/refcount etc.) pointers or garbage collection and 2) with valgrind I don't actually need garbage collection.  The only caveat is test coverage.  I think it's easier to find memory leaks w/ valgrind than with any tool for GC languages (e.g. JVM or .NET languages) that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 5):

one error i notice is this line:

```
 *chrome = (char *) malloc ((size_t) strlen(field));
```

which should be:

```
 *chrome = (char *) malloc ((size_t) strlen(field)+1);
```

This is because a string has a closing 0 at the end which you also have to make room for

Comment: True, but strlen() returns size_t, so drop that cast. And malloc() returns void *, which is convertible to any other (data) pointer type in C, so drop that cast too.

Comment: In this case, you can use strdup() to replace malloc()+strcpy().

Comment: I disagree with the (char *) cast which clearly states the intention.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is that some other part of your code is corrupting memory through a buffer overrun or similar bug.

Although unlikely to be the cause, you have a potential overrun condition in your filename array when the full filename exceeds 100 chars.

I would suggest using a debugger to watch for changes in the memory location used by the merbaseIn variable.

Answer (score 1):

### Generic Pointer Problem

C is a great language but it does require that you not clobber your own memory. Besides the problem previously noted where the malloc is 1 byte short, you may have other pointer problems.

I would suggest [using a memory debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger). In the past, [Electric Fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence) was rather popular but these days I [hear more about valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind). There are lots of other choices.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to error found by [reinier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443164/fclose-causing-segmentation-fault/1443182#1443182), I suspect that:

```
free(chromosome);
```

should be followed by:

```
chromosome = NULL;
```

in order to prevent potential usage of a no longer valid value.

Answer (score 0):

why this FILE** filePtr if only this FILE* filePtr would be enough ?
just a thought...

Comment: using double file pointer when closing is good practice. This way you can set the original file pointer to `NULL` after closing it, since it is not the function argument.

Answer (score 0):

`valgrind` with `memcheck` is definitely the right tool to discover the cause of the segmentation fault. To use a debugger with `valgrind`, note that the `--db-attach` option to `valgrind` has been deprecated since Valgrind 3.10.0 was released in 2014. The release notes state:

```
The built-in GDB server capabilities are superior and should be used
instead. Learn more here:
```

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver

Answer (score 0):

Review every place you used **"malloc"** and see if you made a mistake.

For example, I was putting lines read from a file into a char**, but I incorrectly
malloced it as:

```
my_list = malloc(sizeof(char) * num_lines_found_in_file);
```

When it should have been:

```
my_list = malloc(sizeof(char*)* num_lines_found_in_file);
```