# If fclose(0) is called, does this close stdin?

Tags: c++, c, posix, stdin

If fclose(0) is called, does this close stdin?

The reason why I'm asking this is that for some reason, stdin is being closed in my application and I cannot figure out why.  I checked for fclose (stdin) and this is not in the application and so I was wondering if fclose(0) could cause undefined behaviour such as closing stdin?

If not, what are other ways that stdin could be erroneously closed?

Comment: fileno( stdin ) == 0, but stdin != 0

Comment: You are asking for *wrong* ways to close stdin ? Then I guess most of us are doing it right now :-?

Comment: Are you sure it is being closed *in* your app and not *before* your app? Does `stdin` work correctly at the beginning of one run of your program, and then stop working in the middle of the run? If not, perhaps the program that invoked yours closed (or never set up) stdin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fclose() causing segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443164/fclose-causing-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The signature of `fclose` is this:

```
int fclose ( FILE * stream );
```

That means, `fclose` expects a pointer to `FILE` object. So if you pass `0`, instead of a pointer, `0` would be understood as `NULL` pointer<sup>1</sup>. If its NULL pointer, how do you expect it to close `stdin`? It will not close.  Use `fclose(stdin)`, as `stdin` itself is a pointer to `FILE` object.

I think you're confusing `stdin` with file-descriptor which is of integral type, and usually denoted as `fd`. Its true that `fd` of input stream is `0`. So if you want to use `fd` (instead of `FILE*`), then you've to use `close` from `<unistd.h>`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int close(int fildes);
```

That is, `close(0)` would close stdin.

<sub>1 :  It seems interesting that if you had passed `1` to fclose with the intention to close `stdout`, your code wouldn't even compile, and you would immediately see the problem with your code at compile-time itself. Now the question is, why would it not compile? Because unlike `0`, `1` is not implicitly converted into pointer type. The compiler would generate message like `"error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘FILE*’`. See the error and line number [here at ideone](http://www.ideone.com/mz0yx).</sub>

Comment: @Nawaz But is it safe to use `fclose(stdin)`? Does it produce any undefined behavior? As in, is it any different from calling `close(0)`?

Comment: @Djack: 1) Yes. 2) No. 3) No.

Answer (score 7):

`fclose(0)` invokes **undefined behavior**, so yes, it could do anything, including closing `stdin`. But you have much bigger problems if `fclose(0)` appears in your code.

Answer (score 6):

I think it will take it as `fclose(NULL)`; Which should be undefined and may crash.

Comment: It's sometimes defined AS a crash :) From the Mac OS X man page: The fclose() function does not handle NULL arguments; they will result in a segmentation violation

Answer (score 6):

The following closes stdin:
`close(0);`
`fclose(stdin);`
`close(STDIN_FILENO);`
`daemon(0, 0);`