# How do I get the content of llvm::MemoryBuffer when reading STDIN?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I am using `llvm::MemoryBuffer::getFileOrSTDIN("-")` and, according to the [specification](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MemoryBuffer.html#a2c10acc221149c24051397ea5641b20e), it should *Open the specified file as a MemoryBuffer, **or open stdin if the Filename is "-"***.

Now, in the following context:

```
auto Source = llvm::MemoryBuffer::getFileOrSTDIN(File);

if (std::error_code err = Source.getError()) {
    llvm::errs() << err.message();
} else{
    someFunction(std::move(*Source), File, makeOutputWriter(Format, llvm::outs()),
            IdentifiersOnly, DumpAST);
}
```

it blocks on the first line (when `File == "-"`); as expected as the STDIN never closes.

When a special `*char` appears in STDIN, let's say `<END_CHAR>`, I know that I am finished reading for a given task. How could I close the STDIN in this situations and move on to `someFunction` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can always close the `stdin` file descriptor using [`close`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close), i.e. `close(0)`. If you check [`llvm::MemoryBuffer`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/MemoryBuffer_8cpp_source.html)'s source, you'll see that `getFileOrSTDIN()` basically boils down to a call to `llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemoryBufferForStream()` with the first argument (the file descriptor) set to 0.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951727/if-fclose0-is-called-does-this-close-stdin) SO answer.

The special character to close the standard input is `ctrl-d` (in *nix at least) on the command line (have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-signal-the-end-of-stdin-input)).